# CSS position wrong when update text on textarea

Tags: css, position, textarea

I have a problem about element position when textarea text length change.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child">
            <div class="bar">
                <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The **container** div have position is relative and contain **child** div have position is absolute, in the child div contain a element have position absolute also.

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 780px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.bar textarea {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0
}
```

I have add a event to textarea element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('textarea').keyup(function () {
            $(this).parent().width($(this).width() + 1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I input text into textarea, if text have length overcome the **container**, the child element will have wrong position although the actually position not change.

Before input:
[The textarea position before input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h93on.png)

After input:
[The textarea position after input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SGfB.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you give .bar position: fixed; it will no longer move to the left.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting it to do?

Comment: I want to when I input text into textarea, the textarea don't move to left.